# DirectShow Filters - how to use and find correct filters

Tags: filter, directshow, video-capture

I have a program that was developed using capFilter-"Ds.Net Video Capture Device" and baseGrabFlt-"Ds.Net Grabber".

I am not that familiar with DirectShow and have been trying to determine why this program suddenly stopped working on two machines that it had been working fine. I have used a program to look at the installed filters and don't see any filters named "Ds.Net".

Two questions - can I change these filters? Or how do I find them and install them again on these machines to make the application work again.

Comment: There is no information on your question to reasonably answer you.

Comment: Do you have any code?

take a look at my [post][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201638/forcing-mpeg2demultiplexer-to-use-ffdshow-to-render-h264-digital-tv-video